# Why does SSIS transactions require SQL Server DTC installed?

Tags: ssis

I am looking at SSIS transactions concept and it appears that- for the trasaction functionality to work we must also install SQL server DTC.

Why does SSIS transactions require SQL Server DTC installed?

Comment: You don't need it, unless you try to connect to different database servers under the same transaction. In that case, the transaction is a distributed transaction by definition, so it requires DTC.

Comment: Check [Problem creating a transaction in an SSIS package](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/122610/problem-creating-a-transaction-in-an-ssis-package) at dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ah so this DTC would be required even if normal TSQL transaction is written in SSMS involving 2 different db servers?